# How to give read write permissions to sdcard for android 2.3 emulator?

Tags: android

Hi I need to keep images in my sdcard. So for that I tried to push my images into the sdcard but it is displaying sdcard d-------- in ddms. **How can I give read and write permissions to emulator 2.3.3 version?** Please help me regarding this.....

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think the permission string has changed ever since. Just add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

You need to add "virtual" external memory on your emulator first. In AVD, select your emulator, choose Edit, then type in the size of the sdcard you want under SD Card - Size.

Answer (score 1):

you can follow this tutorial : http://androidblogger.blogspot.de/2009/02/tutorial-how-to-emulate-sd-card-with.html to create an sdCard on your emulator.

Then add this permission : `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` on your manifest file.

Regards,
Sebastien

Answer (score 0):

give `<uses-permission>` in the manifest

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#perms